# Actualizar un Text dentro de una función en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

espero me puedan ayudar, estoy teniendo problemas al momento de actualizar un Text dentro de una función, en la ventana donde esta el widget solo aparecen los textos cuando finaliza por completo el for dentro de la función, y yo quisiera que fuera apareciendo en el Text al mismo tiempo que se va iterando el for, aquí dejo el código que estoy utilizando

```
def GrabarAudio(numero):
        sonidos=[0]*numero
        for j in range(numero):
            obj_audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
            # input('Presiona una tecla')
            entry2.insert(tk.INSERT,'Inicia grabación \n')
            time.sleep(2)
            streaming = obj_audio.open(format=sample,channels=canales,rate=fs,
                        frames_per_buffer=paquete,input=True)
            tramas = []
            sonido = []

            for i in range (0,int(fs/paquete*segundos)):
                datos = streaming.read(paquete)
                tramas.append(datos)
                sonido.append(np.frombuffer(datos,dtype = np.int16))
    
            streaming.stop_stream()
            streaming.close()
            obj_audio.terminate()
            entry2.insert(tk.INSERT,'Grabación finalizada \n')
            sonidos[j]=sonido
   return sonidos

 def Grabar():
        numero=int(var2.get())
        entry2.insert(tk.INSERT,'Grabando....\n')
        sonidos=GrabarAudio(numero)

root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Menú principal')
root.geometry('1500x900')
vent=tk.Frame(root)
entry2=tk.Text(vent)
    entry2.config(font=("Helvetica",15,'bold'))
    entry2.place(x=50, y=430,height=300,width=500)

boton3 = tk.Button(vent, borderwidth=2, image=image2,
                             font=('Helvetica',12,'bold'),
                             height=100,width=100,
                             command=Grabar)    
    boton3.place(x=240, y=300)
```

Espero si puedan ayudarme, mi intención es que en el Text aparezca el iniciando grabación, que termine el proceso y luego aparezca el grabación finalizado pero en tiempo real, porque aparece cuando ya acabo todo el loop completo.

Comment: Y a intente con .insert(), con trace_add(), y con .after() pero al parecer ninguna a funcionado

Comment: Veo que estás usando time.sleep(), ¿estás usando un hilo aparte para correr la función? Tkinter no se lleva bien con sleep y se congela hasta que se termina de ejecutar un proceso (como una llamada a sleep() o una reproducción de audio/video)

Comment: igual se los quite y sigue sin funcionar, el texto aparece cuando se completa el for